# Line Chart x-Axis datapoints with Strings

Tags: chart.js

I want to make a chart.js with multiple lines, which are on the given x-Axis but on different points.

Here is the example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBNZRO

Here is my example dataset:

```js
var data = {
 datasets:[
 {
 label:"Data1",
  data:[
    {x:"2015",y:5},
    {x:"2016",y:10}
  ]
 },
 {
 label:"Data2",
  data:[
    {x:"2016",y:7},
    {x:"test",y:8}
  ]
 }
],
 labels:["2015", "2016", "test"]
};
```

As you see I have strings in my xAxis, this means I cannot use a linear xAxis.

Is there a way to get the x value of the data connected to the right label?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers
Hannes

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure if this is what you want but I create a multiline chart with strings in my xAxis. Please tell me if this is what you want and I will put it has an awnser : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NmVgLO

Comment: Hi, I think I found another solution, cant remember where I used this code. But your answer looks like something i was searching for. So yeah put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has I was saying, this might be a good solution for your problem. 
I've made a simple example demonstrating a multiline chart with strings at xAxis:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NmVgLO

Here you can see how did I build part of the chart "data"

```js
var data = {
     labels:["2015", "2016", "test"],
     datasets:[
     {
         label: "Data1",
         fill: false,
         lineTension: 0.1,
         borderColor: "red",
         pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
         data: [
            {x:"2015",y:5},
            {x:"test",y:10}
         ]
      },
      {
         label: "Data2",
         fill: false,
         lineTension: 0.1,
         borderColor: "blue",
         borderCapStyle: 'square',
         pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
         data: [
             {x:"2015",y:5},
             {x:"2016",y:10}
         ],
         spanGaps: true,
      }
   ]
};
```